# C Shell Scripting - Remove PathName up to FileName

Tags: scripting, csh

So the final part I'm missing in my assignment is a way to print ONLY the file names (rather than ./usr/etc/folder/directory/file.pdf, I want to print file.pdf) but I can't remember how to do this. What is the best/shortest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/basename.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: use /usr/bin/basename

Answer (score 1):

Since using C Shell the correct answer is use string modifier `:t` to get the filename.

Example `set FILENAME = $PATH:t`